# Trying to play an audio file, but an error occurs

Tags: vb.net, windows, audio

So hello there!

I am starting to learn visual basic, but I am getting the following error after trying to play an audio file in the background:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The wave header is corrupt."

I have been trying to find help, but there seems to be none in my case.
Also the code looks like this:

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)Handles  
  Button1.Click

  My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Loïc_Nottet___Rhythm_Inside__Belgium____LIVE_at_Eurovision_2015__Semi_Final_1,AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)

  End Sub

 End Class
```